# Calculating kurtosis by hand vs. numerical integration

Tags: python, r, statistics, numerical-integration

I am calculating the kurtosis of a probability density function via two different methods.

I have 2D maps of normalised specific angular momentum `j/jmean`, velocity dispersion `s` and mass `m` across radii `r`. The velocity dispersion in a given pixel `i` gives rise to a distribution of `j` in that pixel, `PDF_i`, with mean `j/jmean` and standard deviation `r*s/jmean`.

The total PDF is the mass-weighted average of the PDF_i in all of the pixels, `PDF = sum(m*PDF_i)/sum(m)`.

Method 1 involves drawing a sample for each pixel, weighting by the mass, then calculating the kurtosis of the whole set with the cumstats or moments package.

Method 2 involves calculating the kurtosis via numerical integration: `mu_4 = integrate((x-mu)^4 * PDF(x)dx)`.

My minimal working example follows:

```
                                            # test methods for measuring kurtosis of a random distribution.
library(cumstats)
library(moments)
                                        # make a distribution of j, r, sigma, m
set.seed(1)
num <- 100
r <- runif(num)
rd <- 1.5
vflat <- 200
rflat <- 2
v <- vflat*(1-exp(-r/rflat))
s <- exp(-r/rd)
m <- exp(-r/rd)
j <- r*v
jmean <- sum(j*m)/sum(m)
j <- j/jmean
rs <- r*s/jmean

                                        # method 1:
                                        # in every spaxel, generate a PDF(j/jmean) with mean j and width r*s
res <- 300 #samples per spaxel
rho_j  <- rep(NA, res*length(j))
rho_m  <- rep(NA, res*length(m))
for (i in seq(length(j))) {
    rho_j[((i-1)*res+1):(i*res)] <-
        rnorm(res, mean=j[i], sd=(rs[i]))
    rho_m[((i-1)*res+1):(i*res)] <- rep(m[i], res)
}
                                        # apply a mass weighting
rho_jw <- rho_j*rho_m/(sum(rho_m)/num/res) #rho_j*rho_m gives the same results
                                        # use cumstats or moments to measure kurtosis of the whole thing.
b2cs <- cumstats::kurtosis(rho_jw)
b2mm <- moments::kurtosis(rho_jw)

print("res")
print(b2cs)
print(b2mm) # these are the same.

                                        # method 2:
                                        # apply Eq. 8 from paper
aint <- max(j+3*r*s) #integration limits +-A

integ <- function(x, mu, n) {
    (x - mu)^n*sum(m*dnorm(x, mean=j, sd=rs))/sum(m)
}
integrand <- function(x, mu, n) {sapply(x, integ, mu=mu, n=n)}

mu1 <- integrate(integrand, -aint, aint, mu=0, n=1)$value
sd <- sqrt(integrate(integrand, -aint, aint, mu=mu1, n=2)$value)
mu4 <- integrate(integrand, -aint, aint, mu=mu1, n=4)$value
eq8 <- mu4/sd^4

print("eq8")
print(eq8)
```

I expect the two methods to give the same result, but I get different results (res = 1.68; eq8 = 2.21). It would seem that my implementation is causing this, but I cannot see where I am going wrong.

Edit: I have also tried implementing this in python, and can reproduce this effect. I am now suspecting a normalisation issue. Any suggestions would be appreciated.